# mongodb nesting values. "unable to parse: first character in field must be"

Tags: json, mongodb

Mongodb -> developing a product collection. For images I have the following json:

```
"images":{
        "id":"price-1234567890",
        "caption":"image",
        "file":{
            "id":"price-1234567890-1",
            "date_uploaded":"2014-10-01T00:00:00Z",
            "length":"123",
            "md5":"hasg",
            "filename":"price-1234567890-1",
            "url":"/images/folder/mongodb/a.png" 
            },        
        },
```

Trying to insert that information mongodb displays the following information error:

> unable to parse json: first character in field must be [A-Za-z$_], at
>   (11,9)

and displays an error in red in the last },

**Its possible to nest another set of values? (in this case file inside images).**

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is to create an array of objects. This will allow you to have multiple objects under file.

```js
{
 "images": {
  "id": "price-1234567890",
  "caption": "image",
  "file": [{
   "id": "price-1234567890-1",
   "date_uploaded": "2014-10-01T00:00:00Z",
   "length": "123",
   "md5": "hasg",
   "filename": "price-1234567890-1",
   "url": "/images/folder/mongodb/a.png"
  }, {
   "id": "price-1234567890-1",
   "date_uploaded": "2014-10-01T00:00:00Z",
   "length": "123",
   "md5": "hasg",
   "filename": "price-1234567890-1",
   "url": "/images/folder/mongodb/a.png"
  }]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the comma after closing bracket of "file" object would do the trick.

```
"images": {
    "id":"price-1234567890",
    "caption":"image",
    "file": {
        "id":"price-1234567890-1",
        "date_uploaded":"2014-10-01T00:00:00Z",
        "length":"123",
        "md5":"hasg",
        "filename":"price-1234567890-1",
        "url":"/images/folder/mongodb/a.png" 
       }        
    },
```